# Codenameone: Textfield size and format getting changed after keyboard appered

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

I have developed an app using codename one.I have made registration form which having six textfield and a button.After focusing first textfield keyboard appears on screen then textfield size and formatting changes.I have attached screenshot.It was working fine but since 2 -3 days after updating libraries at the time of build those issues came in place.
Textfield size and formatting should remain original after keyboard appears.
Please help me to solve this issue???

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code you used for this? Is the parent container scrollable on the Y axis?

Comment: I used Table layout for parent container and it's not scrollable on Y axis.It was working fine but since 3-4 days this problem occurred.

Answer (score 0):

A text field must be within a scrollable Y container otherwise you will experience undefined behavior that might work on some cases but fail on others. We need the scrollability so we can give room for the keyboard and resize the components.

It's possible that [theming changes discussed here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/pixel-perfect-text-input.html) impacted your UI making it larger and effectively forcing this. Regardless of that the solution is still adding scrollablity.